# T-SQL "partition by" results not as expected

Tags: t-sql, partition-by

What I'm trying to do is get a total count of "EmailAddresses" via using partitioning logic. As you can see in the result set spreadsheet, the first record is correct - this particular email address exists 109 times. But, the second record, same email address, the `numberOfEmailAddresses` column shows 108. And so on - just keeps incrementing downward by 1 on the same email address. Clearly, I'm not writing this SQL right and I was hoping to get some feedback as to what I might be doing wrong.

What I would like to see is the number 109 consistently down the column `numberOfEmailAddresses` for this particular email address. What might I be doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
select
    Q1.SubscriberKey,
    Q1.EmailAddress,
    Q1.numberOfEmailAddresses
from
    (select
        sub.SubscriberKey as SubscriberKey,
        sub.EmailAddress as EmailAddress,
        count(*) over (partition by sub.EmailAddress order by sub.SubscriberKey asc) as numberOfEmailAddresses
    from    
        ent._Subscribers sub) Q1
```

And here's my result set, ordered by "numberOfEmailAddresses":
[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result and please do not post image. Use formatted text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct
    Q1.SubscriberKey,
    Q1.EmailAddress,
(select count(*) from ent._Subscribers sub where sub.EmailAddress = Q1.EmailAddress) as numberOfEmailAddress
from ent._Subscribers Q1
```

will get you what you want.  I think the inclusion of the order by in your partition function is what is causing the descending count.  Ordering in a partition function further subdivides the partition as I understand it.

```
select
    Q1.SubscriberKey,
    Q1.EmailAddress,
    Q1.numberOfEmailAddresses
from
    (select
        sub.SubscriberKey as SubscriberKey,
        sub.EmailAddress as EmailAddress,
        count(*) over (partition by sub.EmailAddress) as numberOfEmailAddresses
    from    
        ent._Subscribers sub) Q1
```

May also work but I can't find a suitable dataset to test.

Comment: +1 for the second solution. From the documentation: If it(ORDER BY) is specified, and a ROWS/RANGE is not specified, then default RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW is used as default for window frame by the functions that can accept optional ROWS/RANGE specification (for example min or max).

Comment: The second code block works! Thanks Chris!